# показать спрятать текст

Tags: jquery, html, вёрстка

```
<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
<a href="#" class="more" >Показать</a>
<div>
    <p>text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more </p>
</div>

<p>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </p>
<a href="#" class="more" >Показать</a>
<div>
    <p>text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more text more </p>
</div>
```

Как сделать на jquery показать скрыть текст, надо что бы в ссылке менялось название ПОКАЗАТЬ на СПРЯТАТЬ и текст плавное выезжал слайдом, и обратно по клику. И он должен отрквать следующий после него (ссылки) блок див. ЗА ранее спасибо)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Как-то так можно](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7hsdY/), а в остальном надо смотреть на конкретную структуру.

Answer (score 1):

Вас в Yandex забанили? Ищется за пару секунд.

- [Свойство display](http://htmlbook.ru/css/display)
- [display:none; displays 'none' in browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598110/displaynone-displays-none-in-browser)
- [Свойство "display"](http://learn.javascript.ru/display)